# Enum dependency property is set to null when using a WPF style property setter in Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro, dependency-properties

In our Metro application I have an attached property which is of an `enum` type.

When setting the property on the element directly as an XAML attribute the value gets set fine, but when using a `Setter` element in a style, though the property is set it is set to a `null` value (that is, `e.NewValue` in the code below is null)

Why is this? It is causing issues and obviously cannot be cast to the enum type. Thanks.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyboardScrollRestrictionStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("KeyboardScrollRestrictionStyle", typeof(KeyboardScrollRestrictionStyle), typeof(FlipViewScrollBehaviour),
            new PropertyMetadata(KeyboardScrollRestrictionStyle.TextBox, OnKeyboardScrollRestrictionStyleChanged));

    static void OnKeyboardScrollRestrictionStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
       //I check e.NewValue at breakpoint
    }
```

This works (e.NewValue is TextBox):

```
<TemplatedControls:WatermarkTextBox       
Behaviours:FlipViewScrollBehaviour.KeyboardScrollRestrictionStyle="TextBox"
/>
```

This doesn't (e.NewValue is null):

```
<Style x:Key="TimesheetLineListViewItemTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Behaviours:FlipViewScrollBehaviour.KeyboardScrollRestrictionStyle" Value="TextBox" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the attached property in your textBox locally and then trying to override it with Setter in your style that's the only case i can guess which will stop this from working. eg -

```
<TemplatedControls:WatermarkTextBox    
Behaviours:FlipViewScrollBehaviour.KeyboardScrollRestrictionStyle="TextBox"
Style ="{StaticResource TimesheetLineListViewItemTextBox}"/>
```

Here you are setting it locally and if tries to set in style setter, it won't work. Refer to this link - [Dependency Property Precedence Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly this is not the issue as all controls that use this style do not have it explicitly set, and yet the issue still occurs.